# How to add class to a kendo grid table header?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

Here is my kendo grid,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<example.Web.Areas.Models.PredictedValues>()
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.Bound(p => p.Rlno).Title("Roll no").HtmlAttributes(new { @class =     "someclass" });
        column.Bound(p => p.stdname).Width(60).Title("Std name").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
        column.Bound(p => p.school).Width(50).Title("School").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
    })
))
```

I need to apply some stylings through class to the header names. the included @class is not working for the header. Instead, it is bounding to the table rows. How do i do? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
column.Bound(p => p.Rlno).Title("Roll no").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "someclass" });
```

Answer (score 2):

.HeaderHtmlAttributes adds a class to the header only.

To add a css class to the gridcell - as an example here I am targetting the Status column - you want to style the grid values... you want to do this instead.

```
 columns.Bound(m => m.Status).Title("Status").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "someclass" });
```